# Client ID undefined in initTokenClient call

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-api, google-api-js-client

I need to acquire access token for accessing google sheets api. This is a code inside Next.js page, which is also denoted as `'use client'`.
Google api library script is loaded like so:

```
<Script 
    src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" 
    async={true}
/>
```

Client is being initialized in a function, that is triggered by a button press, so we can be sure, google api library has already been loaded:

```
let client = window?.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: '[CLIENT_ID].apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    callback: onSignIn,
    auto_select: true,
})
```

But when `window?.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` is called, i get an error in the console:
[image: Error]

When i inspect the network tab, i can see that the `client_id` is not being passed on:
[image]

[image]